# Woocommerce - Add to Cart on Out of Stocks Items

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

i'm using Woocommerce for doing a ecommerce site and i need to get the option to Add to Cart even if the item is out of stock.

How can i achieve this ?

Thanks and have a nice day !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done by:

Going to your dashboard -> WooCommerce -> Products -> Inventory -> Untick the "Out of Stock Visibility" checkbox.

Next go to the `Products` tab -> `Edit product` in question -> in the `Product Data` section click on the `Inventory link` and change the `Allow Backorders?` dropdown list to `Allow` or `Allow, but notify customer`.