# How disabled exception in class-wc-cart.php?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

How add to cart item out of stock?
The exception to this is the exception in class-wc-cart.php:

```
// Stock check - only check if we're managing stock and backorders are not allowed
            if ( ! $product_data->is_in_stock() ) {
                throw new Exception( sprintf( __( 'You cannot add &quot;%s&quot; to the cart because the product is out of stock.', 'woocommerce' ), $product_data->get_name() ) );
            }
```

I trying:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data_custom',5,6 );

function woocommerce_add_cart_item_data_custom( $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id, $variation, $cart_item_data) {
$product_data = wc_get_product( $product_id );
    $cart_item_data = (array) apply_filters( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', $cart_item_data, $product_id, $variation_id );
    $cart_id        = WC()->cart->generate_cart_id( $product_id, $variation_id, $variation, $cart_item_data );
    $cart_item_key  = WC()->cart->find_product_in_cart( $cart_id );

    // Stock check - only check if we're managing stock and backorders are not allowed
            if ( ! $product_data->is_in_stock() ) {
                continue;
            }
    return false;
}
```

But not working!!! Please help!!!

Comment: This is a setting in WooCommerce.  No coding required: https://stackoverflow.com/q/22666143/870729

Comment: This is a setting is absent in Woocomerce !!!!! I need the product setting : "out of stock" and Allow Backorders?: "Allow, but notify customer". But if product out of stock and Allow Backorders item not add to cart!

Comment: I saw all answers already!!!

Comment: I need disabled  exception: "throw new Exception( sprintf( __( 'You cannot add &quot;%s&quot; to the cart because the product is out of stock.', 'woocommerce' ), $product_data->get_name() ) );"
            }

Comment: Look here: https://conschneider.de/manage-stock-backorders-woocommerce/ "Backorders only are possible for as long as the stock status is “in stock”. Setting the product to out of stock will again block purchases and display “out of stock”." You should put your stock to 0 or lower and leave the "In Stock" as the Stock Status setting.

Comment: Are you kidding me? I know it!!! I need disabled exception: "throw new Exception( sprintf( __( 'You cannot add &quot;%s&quot; to the cart because the product is out of stock.', 'woocommerce' ), $product_data->get_name() ) );" }